# App force closes when "Always" option is selected in "Complete action using" dialog

Tags: android, image, cordova, crop, cordova-plugins

In my application I need to capture or pick image from gallery and then crop it. Following is an example screenshot:

[image: Crop image with...]

When **Just once** is selected it works normal (able to crop). But the problem occurs when **Always** is selected: **either the app force closes or the image could not be loaded**.

The Logcat didn't show any error message (the app force closes when it reaches startactivity).

Here is the source code:

```
public class CropImage extends CordovaPlugin{
    public final String ACTION_GET_IMAGE_NAME = "GetImageName";
    Uri myUri;
    int RESULT_CANCELED = 0;
    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) {

        boolean result = false;
        if(action.equals(ACTION_GET_IMAGE_NAME)) {
            try {
                myUri = Uri.parse(args.getString(0));
                cropCapturedImage(myUri);
            } catch (JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            result = true;
        }


        return result;
    }

    public void cropCapturedImage(Uri picUri){

        Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        //indicate image type and Uri of image
        cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
        //set crop properties
        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
        String[] separated = String.valueOf(picUri).split("/");
        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/novema/files/ski/"+separated[7]);
        cropIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));            
        cropIntent.putExtra("output", Uri.fromFile(f)); 
        cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", false);

        //start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
        this.cordova.startActivityForResult((CordovaPlugin) this,cropIntent, 2);
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

        if(resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED && intent != null){
            if(requestCode == 2){

                Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
                //get the cropped bitmap from extras
                Bitmap thePic = extras.getParcelable("data");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Is that any way to hide the "Always" option? Or is there any other solution?

Comment: Hello please refer to this link and follow the steps given.... [Link](http://androidtutorialbd.blogspot.in/2012/11/android-image-crop.html)

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solved the issue using above answer. What i did means i just remove the **ALWAYS** and **JUST ONCE** options in complete action.

Like

```
 this.cordova.startActivityForResult((CordovaPlugin) this,cropIntent, 2);
```

this line replaced like this

```
this.cordova.startActivityForResult(this,Intent.createChooser(cropIntent, "Choose App to crop "), 2);
```